# How to replace {asd} with 123?

Tags: php

How to replace {asd} with 123 with php? I've a function to replace the string

```
   <?php
    function show($text) {
      $find = array(
       '{asd}' => "123"
      );
      return preg_replace($find,'',$text);
    }
    $text = "{asd}";
    $htmltext = show($text);
    echo $htmltext;
```

Comment: why not use `str_replace` or `preg_repalce` directly ? and expected output is `{123}` or `123` ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is specific to OP question. There are much better solution available.

If you want output as `123`:

```
function show($text) {
    $find = array(
    '/{asd}/',
    );
    return preg_replace($find,'123',$text);
}
$text = "{asd}";
$htmltext = show($text);
echo $htmltext;
```

If you want output as `{123}`:

```
function show($text) {
    $find = array(
    '/asd/',
    );
    return preg_replace($find,'123',$text);
}
$text = "{asd}";
$htmltext = show($text);
echo $htmltext;
```

Check example #2 in [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for how to use array as parameters.

> Example #2 Using indexed arrays with preg_replace()
>
> ```
> <?php
> $string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
> $patterns = array();
> $patterns[0] = '/quick/';
> $patterns[1] = '/brown/';
> $patterns[2] = '/fox/';
> $replacements = array();
> $replacements[2] = 'bear';
> $replacements[1] = 'black';
> $replacements[0] = 'slow';
> echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> The bear black slow jumped over the lazy dog.
> ```
>
> By ksorting patterns and replacements, we should get what we wanted.
>
> ```
> <?php
> ksort($patterns);
> ksort($replacements);
> echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> The slow black bear jumped over the lazy dog.
> ```

Comment: nope.... want by writing in html code {asd} to show 123 .. or {hhfdhdf} .. = 864 ..

Comment: '{asd}' => '123' and it was so .. nope
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'bear';

Comment: how `{hhfdhdf} .. = 864` ?

Comment: @I.Nikolaew please be specific in your question. comment section will only help me, not others. :) Please write the logic as well. Currently by looking at your question one can think only of replace from `{abc}` to `123`

Comment: $find = array(
       '{asd}' => "123",
     '{hhfdhdf}' => "864",
     '{hijhi}' => "hfcfdh"

      );

Comment: sorry not able to get it.

Comment: in phpbb the translation was done so ...

Comment: how to do so if in html file there is {name} .. to show WebSite
PHP Code:
$lang = array(
'name' => 'WebSite',
'more' => 'More...'
);

include('inc/message.html'); 
message.html code:
Welcome in {name}. {more}

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your end result should be but for a string replace like that I would personally use sprintf.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Edit:
You could simply do this.

```
$find['{asd}'] = "123";
$text = 'There are %d in here';
$output = sprintf($text, $find['{asd}']);
echo $output;
```

This would echo "There are 123 in here". You can use %s for string if needed (%d means integer).

Comment: where there is {asd} to show 123
php code: '{asd}' => '123'
html code: {asd}
show: 123